# How to mark all packages under dev-ruby/ with keywords "~amd64" in portage?

Tags: ruby, gentoo

I would like to use the `~amd64` test branch for `dev-ruby/*` packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official Gentoo documentation](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=3&chap=3#doc_chap2) says that you should add the desired packages (and versions, if needed) at `/etc/portage/package.keywords`. Look at these examples:

```
# This will accept any ~arch version:
dev-ruby/png
# This will accept only this specific version:
=dev-ruby/png-1.2.0
# This will accept all versions that start with "1.2.0"
=dev-ruby/png-1.2.0*
# This will accept any version below 1.3
<dev-ruby/png-1.3
```

Thus, you should get a list of the packages you want to install, and add them to this file. There is no way to get all packages from a category, you must explicitly list each one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gem` to manage ruby related packages might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eix to get list all packages in a single category.

```
emerge eix
```

Then run `eix-update` to update the eix database.

Once `eix` is up to date, here's a oneliner that will do what you're asking:

```
eix dev-ruby/ | grep "dev-ruby/" --after 1 | grep "~" --before 1 | awk -F"*" '/dev-ruby/{print $2" ~amd64"}' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//g' | tee -a /etc/portage/package.keywords
```

And just to make sure it's adding the right stuff, you can use this one instead prior to using the one above, as a test:

```
eix dev-ruby/ | grep "dev-ruby/" --after 1 | grep "~" --before 1 | awk -F"*" '/dev-ruby/{print $2" ~amd64"}' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//g' | tee -a /dev/null
```